# How to add a property to NSObject in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm using the following code to add a `displayValue` method to NSObject:

```
@interface NSObject (MyNSObjectAdditions)
- (NSString*)displayValue;
@end


@implementation NSObject (MyNSObjectAdditions)
- (NSString*)displayValue {
    return self.description;
}
@end
```

This works great, but really I'd rather have displayValue be a read-only property instead of a method.

What would be the proper syntax to convert `displayValue` to be a property instead of a selector, if it's even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only add new methods to a class using categories.  If you really want to add new instance variables, you will have to subclass NSObject.

In any case, adding functionalities to NSObject is rarely a good idea. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have to disagree with you. I've added categories to NSObject plenty of times. It's a perfectly valid option for adding behavior to pretty much everything in your class tree at once.  You just need to take care not to clobber any existing methods.

Comment: Also disagree with the other point. If you want to add new instance variables without subclassing, you can use this technique: [Objective-C : adding attribute to a category](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4597637/1804403)

Comment: Associated objects (`objc_{get,set}AssociatedObject`) can be used as a fully-functional replacement to adding instance variables to objects dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

You can have properties in categories. In categories that are not [class extensions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW2) (AKA class continuations), you can't use @synthesize. However, it's simple to write backing methods instead. In your case, this works:

```
@interface NSObject (MyNSObjectAdditions)
@property (readonly) NSString *displayValue;
@end

@implementation NSObject (MyNSObjectAdditions)

- (NSString *)displayValue {
    return self.description;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your -displayValue method doesn't add anything to -description.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: By default -displayValue returns -description, but doing this allows me to subclass -displayValue in other objects on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Why don't you just override -description on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: Because overriding description has far reaching effects.  Other parts of the code may rely on descriptions being output in a particular way and I don't want to change that.  Besides, conceptually I'm not really changing what an object should "look like", just how it should be rendered in this particular module (which outputs html in this example).

Comment: I often override `description` to stick in custom info. If you're familiar with Java, you can think of it just like `.toString`, essentially a stub for a formatted dump of the object. I would say you are correct to create another method for an HTML rendering.

Comment: Making code dependent on the contents of the string you get from -description is a Very Bad Idea.  That method is there for debugging purposes.

Comment: Also consider overridding debugDescription instead of description, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think some of you are missing the point here. He's just using the _value of_ `self.description` as a stub value for `.displayValue`. Otherwise, `.displayValue` belongs to him, and he's going to do more interesting things with it on a class-by-class basis.