# Objective-C : adding attribute to a category

Tags: objective-c, attributes, categories

I have built a category for NSDate and I would like to encapsulate an attribute in this category to hold some data. But I can't achieve adding this attribute, only methods.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here some Code:

Filename: NSObject+dictionary.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
@interface NSObject (dictionary)
- (NSMutableDictionary*) getDictionary;
@end
```

Filename: NSObject+dictionary.m

```
#import "NSObject+dictionary.h"
@implementation NSObject (dictionary)
- (NSMutableDictionary*) getDictionary
{
  if (objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @"dictionary")==nil) 
  {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self,@"dictionary",[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init],OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
  }
  return (NSMutableDictionary *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @"dictionary");
}
```

Now every instance (of every class) has a dictionary, where you can store your custom attributes.
With [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) you can set a value like this:

```
[myObject setValue:attributeValue forKeyPath:@"dictionary.attributeName"]
```

And you can get the value like this:

```
[myObject valueForKeyPath:@"dictionary.attributeName"]
```

That even works great with the Interface Builder and User Defined Runtime Attributes.

```
Key Path                   Type                     Value
dictionary.attributeName   String(or other Type)    attributeValue
```

Comment: this answer is incomplete. This solution doesn't allow the property/ivar to be accessed from inside the category, from a class method, for example.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add instance variables in categories.

However, you can add storage for your attribute to an object using *[associative references](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH24-SW1)*.  Note that if you need to add more than one attribute, rather than adding an associative reference for each, you're probably better off adding a single reference to (say) an NSMutableDictionary, CFMutableDictionaryRef, or NSMapTable and using that for all of your attributes.

Comment: if I understand what is said, associative reference cannot be done inside the category but outside for an object instanciated. Is that right ?

Answer (score 2):

[`objc_setAssociatedObject()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW67) and [`objc_getAssociatedObject()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_getAssociatedObject)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add attribute to class, you can try to use [github.com/libObjCAttr](https://github.com/epam/lib-obj-c-attr). It's really easy to use, add it via pods, and then you can add attribute like that:

```
RF_ATTRIBUTE(YourAttributeClass, property1 = value1)
@interface NSDate (AttributedCategory)
@end
```

And in the code:

```
YourAttributeClass *attribute = [NSDate RF_attributeForClassWithAttributeType:[YourAttributeClass class]];
// Do whatever you want with attribute
NSLog(@"%@", attribute.property1)
```